# Richfaces: Trigger event after table is rendered

Tags: java, jquery, jsf

I am using a rich:dataTable with facelets to display data. The table also includes filters in the header.

Does anyone know how I can automatically fire a trigger after the table rows are rendered to refresh certain filter columns.

The table has an id of ${id}table. The relevant filters are in a4j:outputPanel components.

Can I use jQuery to automatically fire an event to reRender certain filter columns after the table has been rendered. Can I link jQuery to the table with something like:

```
<rich:jQuery selector="##{id}table tr"
         query="<do something action to rerender a list of components>" />
```

Please advise.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used facelets before but something like this in your `<head>` element might work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var reloadElements = function () {
            //do your reloading here
        };
    });
</script>
```

It should be noted that you will also need to include the jQuery library in the page that gets loaded.